# Git Subtree add failing on project .gitignore file (using Windows)

Tags: windows, git, azure-devops

I am attempting to merge two repository projects on a windows machine using git subtree.

I setup a remote reference to the project

`git remote add -f ProjectB <project b repo path>`

When I run the subtree add command :

`git subtree add --prefix ProjectB\ClientApp ProjectB develop --squash`

I encounter the following error:

`error: invalid path 'ProjectB\ClientApp/.gitignore'`

I also encountered this on a .editorconfig file for VS that was in the project accidentally. We also have some .prettier files in Project B that I imagine are going to cause issues in the same manner.

Does this sound like an issue with Windows path settings, or is it a problem with git?

**Specs:**
GIT: 2.30.02
REPO HOST: AzureDevops
INTERFACE: powershell, cmder, sourcetree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was me (and kind of Windows)

After changing the slashes to forward slashes, the command was able to run.

`git subtree add --prefix ProjectB\ClientApp ProjectB develop --squash`
**change to**
`git subtree add --prefix ProjectB/ClientApp ProjectB develop --squash`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Done. Meant to do that but that 24 hour waiting period for waiting to accept your own answer pushed this out of my mind. Thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: I had a similar issue on mac using "git subtree add -P ./path/to/folder CLONE_URL HEAD". The problem was the dot at "./path/to/folder". It worked with "git subtree add -P path/to/folder CLONE_URL HEAD"